# Android Cookies for IP address

Tags: android, cookies, webview, ip

I have HttpSessions with number of servers. The main issue was that if I logged in via WebView then my cookies is not available for the http connection. I fixed it with retrieving cookie for my URL and setting it as Cookie header for all my http connection to that URL.

But the problem I can't solve is that if I have IP address as my server host URL, then trying to retrieve cookie with CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(ipAddress) returns null.

Should I made alias for my ip server host? Or maybe there is any solution from client side, cause in my iOS application it works nice.

One thing - I haven't tried on the IP address only yet. My IP address also contains port number, but cookies are not port-abailable, so I think they should be available with getCookie("http://MY_IP"), but they are not. But I think that it can be new surprise and port number can break the logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In our app we came across the same issue. We ended up using [Square's OkHttp library](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) which is faster and easier than default android libs. You can add it by adding these lines to your build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.1.0'
```

Once that's in place, this is how we set the cookies to be shared between the webview and OkHttp. I'm sure there's a way to do this with the default Http client as well:

```
public static OkHttpClient getClient(){
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    //set cookies as shared across webview and web requests
    WebkitCookieManagerProxy coreCookieManager = new WebkitCookieManagerProxy(null,
            java.net.CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
    java.net.CookieHandler.setDefault(coreCookieManager);

    okHttpClient.setCookieHandler(coreCookieManager);
    return okHttpClient;
}
```

WebkitCookieManagerProxy looks like this:

```
//sets cookies as the same across WebView and HttpUrlConnection
public class WebkitCookieManagerProxy extends CookieManager{
private android.webkit.CookieManager webkitCookieManager;

public WebkitCookieManagerProxy()
{
    this(null, null);
}

public WebkitCookieManagerProxy(CookieStore store, CookiePolicy cookiePolicy)
{
    super(null, cookiePolicy);

    this.webkitCookieManager = android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance();
}

@Override
public void put(URI uri, Map<String, List<String>> responseHeaders) throws IOException
{
    // make sure our args are valid
    if ((uri == null) || (responseHeaders == null)) return;

    // save our url once
    String url = uri.toString();

    // go over the headers
    for (String headerKey : responseHeaders.keySet())
    {
        // ignore headers which aren't cookie related
        if ((headerKey == null) || !(headerKey.equalsIgnoreCase("Set-Cookie2") || headerKey.equalsIgnoreCase("Set-Cookie"))) continue;

        // process each of the headers
        for (String headerValue : responseHeaders.get(headerKey))
        {
            this.webkitCookieManager.setCookie(url, headerValue);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public Map<String, List<String>> get(URI uri, Map<String, List<String>> requestHeaders) throws IOException
{
    // make sure our args are valid
    if ((uri == null) || (requestHeaders == null)) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Argument is null");

    // save our url once
    String url = uri.toString();

    // prepare our response
    Map<String, List<String>> res = new java.util.HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    // get the cookie
    String cookie = this.webkitCookieManager.getCookie(url);

    // return it
    if (cookie != null) res.put("Cookie", Arrays.asList(cookie));
    return res;
}

@Override
public CookieStore getCookieStore()
{
    // we don't want anyone to work with this cookie store directly
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
}
```

Now, when you log in with the webview, the cookies will be shared with the http requests (if you use OkHttpClient).

Comment: It looks like WebkitCookieManagerProxy is your custom class ?

Comment: Also, thanks for solution, but my temporary solution for this issue is OK. But what about IP addresses as URL ?

Comment: Apologies. Added WebkitCookieManagerProxy. Also an IP address will work fine with this solution.

Comment: Oh, that thanks. A'll try it after having lunch and let you know. :)

Comment: For your temporary solution you'll need to set the IP address as a string if it isn't already. _Edit_ Another thought--you also may need 'http://' before the beginning of the IP address.

Comment: I do not know what's wrong with Android manager of different networking thinks, including cookie, but your solution is working, thanks a lot!